# Alignment issues with button on header using bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3. Here is my HTML page:
[image]
As you can see the star is downside to the title. I want to align with title
Here is my html code:

```
<p class="pull-right visible-xs">
            <h3><center>2000 Cadillac Eldorado Esc (Prospect heights) $3500 
              <button type="button" class="btn bookmark" id="1799" > 
                <span class="
                  glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty "></span>
              </button>
              </center>
            </h3>
          </p>
```

and css:

```
button.bookmark {
  border:none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
 }

 .btn.bookmark .glyphicon {
  line-height: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23352666/align-button-icon-with-button-in-html-css-bootstrap-3/23352769?noredirect=1#comment35767035_23352769) only works when the icon is adjacent to a `.btn`.
The idea being that the two align perfectly as if they were two `.btn`s.

In this case you don't need the `.btn` class, you can just set the vertical align on the button.

```
<button type="button" class="bookmark" id="1799">

button.bookmark {
  border:none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/heqab/1/edit)**

Comment: can I have one that works in both with and without buttons , i.e something that works for both of my posts?

Comment: `position: relative` and `top: 2px` seems best. http://jsbin.com/heqab/3/edit  Or seen as Bootstrap already puts a `top: 1px` on glyphicons, you could override it in this instance http://jsbin.com/heqab/4/edit

Answer (score 1):

I believe the line-height in your css that's causing it.  It is inheriting the attribute and it might be smaller causing it to have too much space above it.  If you have a link I can check it in firebug.  If not try messing with that.  You can also find some cool info about it [Here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-height/)

Hopefully that helps,  Let me know if that does it